# Listview bound to ObservableCollection, how to get current ObservableCollection item if each listviewitem contains a checkbox you can click on

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

I started with m xaml journey yesterday, and I am still struggling with several things.
What I am trying to achieve:

1. [X] Make a listview
2. [X] Bind the listview to an Observable Collection
3. [X] Make a Listview item template with certain items in it
4. [?] When you click on a checkbox in the Listview item, pass the current ITEM from the Observable Collection to the eventhandlers that will handle the on checked and on unchecked events.

Possible answers:

1. I am assuming that I might be able to cast the object back to a checkbox, and then traverse the Listview until I find the specific checkbox, then get that ITEM, but I don't really like this solution.
2. It seems that you might be able to make a class where you inherit the ICommandInferface, but I don't understand how to do the binding in xaml to get the current item.

```xml
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SourceInfoDataSource}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:Name="SourceInfoListItem">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding Path=Show, Converter={StaticResource VisibleIfTrueConverter}}">
                                <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked"></CheckBox>
                                <Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <!--<ImageBrush ImageSource="Placeholder.png"/>-->
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFF0000" />
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="={Binding Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource valueToStringConverter}}"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned SourceInfoDataSource is an ObservableCollection (of T) but what is T?  Is it a type that is : INotifyPropertyChanged?  If so, I'd consider binding the Checkbox-> IsChecked to a property on T like "IsSelected".  In this case, you could subscribe to the PropertyChanged event on each instance of T and when that event handler hits, you can check the e.PropertyName is "IsSelected" and sender (cast to T)'s IsSelected == true